# Why surjectivity is necessary for the image of normal subgroup in $G$ to be normal in $G'$

Tags: group-theory

Let $f$ be a group morphism, $f:G\rightarrow G'$. Then it is a well known fact that $H\lhd G \implies f(H) \lhd f(G)$. So in general $f(H)$ is not normal in $G',$ unless f is surjective. I am asked to give a counterexample. Let's take  $G\lhd G$, then $f(G)<G'.$ Moreover, $\forall x \in G, f(x)f(G)=f(xG)=f(Gx)=f(G)f(x)$, which is another way of stating that $f(G)\lhd f(G).$ For $y \notin f(G), yf(G) $ can not be written as $f(xG)$ since there is no such $x\in G$ such that $y=f(x).$ I am though unsatisfied since in general it can occur that $yf(G)=f(G)y,\ \forall y\in G'.$

Can somebody complete my counterexample or give an other one as to show why surjectivity is a necessary condition ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take any subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ which is not normal and $i:H\rightarrow G$ the canonical embedding, $i(H)$ is not normal.

Comment: But the condition is $H \lhd G$ and not the contrary as you are stating.

Comment: $H$ is normal in $H$ but $i(H)$ is not normal in $G$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's very simple and yet very accurate.